# Question about the Expression board of Contour

Tags: contour, palantir-foundry

In the expression board of Foundry's countour I want to group a column based upon its value in this case "amount". If choose Column = 'amount' I get a group by value: "true" and "false". I would like to get only the group by 'amount' and instead of true and false, the value amount. Who can help and what am I doing wrong.

see my tries mentioned above

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to group a column, you can either use the `OVER (PARTITION BY...` syntax or use an Aggregation expression. Either way, you need some aggregate you want to compute, such as COUNT or SUM. What are you trying to compute that requires grouping the column by the amount value? Could you use the chart, distribution, or histogram boards?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use the Expression board?
There is a "Group By" board that provides the requested functionality (assuming "amount" is a numeric type and not a string type).